# getopt not getting parameters in some order

Tags: c, getopt

I'm using `getopt` to parse the parameters from the command line, and I have problems to make it recognize the optional parameter order.

I want to achieve these cases:

```
$ ./program -i file.html -o output.html #ex 1
$ ./program -i -o file.html output.html #ex 2
$ ./program -o output.html -i file.html #ex 3
```

my code looks like this

```
while((c = getopt(argc, argv, "hi:o:")) != -1) {
    switch(c) {
        case 'h':
            //prints the help file
            break;
        case 'i':
            ivalue = optarg;
            break;
        case 'f':
            fvalue = optarg;
            break;
        case '?':
            //prints an error
            break;
        default:
            abort();
    }
}
```

to debug better this I've also wrote outside the while

```
for(int i = optind; i < argc; i++) {
    printf("non optional argument %s\n", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

so the examples 1 and 3 are correctly working, while the example 2 is not getting the parameters straight. At first I thought that it was simply not possible with this function, but then in [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/getopt.html) example I saw it was.

There's also a bonus question: how come calling the program with no parameters doesn't `abort()`?

I'm using ubuntu 15.10 and gcc 5.2.1 installed with apt-get (dunno if useful but better safe that sorry).

Comment: Example #2 does not follow the standard POSIX command line format (implemented by `getopt`).  Option arguments must follow the option directly.

Comment: The example you linked to has confused you.  You see option `-a` being swapped around to different positions, but note that that option does not accept an argument.  Option `-o` does accept an argument, and note that none of the examples there insert `-a` between `-o` and its argument.  As @interjay observed, when an option accepts an argument, that argument must follow the option directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> in [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/getopt.html) example I saw it was [possible].

No, you didn't.  Your option `-i` requires an argument, but in your non-working case you try to insert a different option between the `-i` and its argument.  That is not allowed -- if an option takes an argument, whether optional or required, that argument (if provided) must immediately follow the option letter.  The example you linked does not show differently.

What you are trying to do not only is not supported by `getopt()`, it does not follow standard Unix convention.  Moreover, although it could conceivably work the way you imagine for options with *required* arguments, it is wholly unworkable for options with *optional* arguments.  When arguments are optional, there is no way to correctly match them with their options if they are not required to follow directly.

> There's also a bonus question: how come calling the program with no parameters doesn't abort()?

Why would it?  If no options are specified to the program on its command line then `getopt()` returns -1 on the first call, and the loop body is never executed.  To get an `abort()` from your code, you would need to specify an option that is in the option string, but for which you do not provide a specific case, or else an option that requires an argument, but without providing the argument (in which event `getopt()` returns `':'`, for which you do not provide a specific case).  As the code is presently written, that would need to be `-o`, either with or without an argument, or `-i` without an argument.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't possible with `getopt`. The `"i:"` in your optstring means that if the `-i` option is present, it must have argument. In your second example this means that `-o` is interpreted as the argument to `-i` and not as an option.

If you're on Linux and linking with glibc you can use the `::` GNU extension (eg. `"hi::o:"`) to make `-i` take an optional argument. However this would break your first and third examples as the optional argument is required to appear immediately after option (eg. `-ifile.html`).

Answer (score 0):

To get around this "limitation"... I'd more call it intended functionality, I used flags and functions. You move through each getopt argument and set flags and variables as you pass through (and in some cases send to functions to get returns and unset other flags if you want a particular one to take precedent over another. Then once complete you perform some mental math to determine what happens in what order.

For example for a script to make ACL setting easier for an end user (psuedocode areas are clearly marked):

```
getHelp () {
    printf "\nThis does stuff with [OPTIONS] and stuff...\n\n"
    exit 0
}
main () {
    if [[ $targetFile == "-h" ]]; then
        usage
        exit 0
    fi
    [[ ! -f $targetFile ]] && [[ ! -d $targetF ]] && {
        printf "\nYou must specify a target File or Folder. Exiting.\n"
        exit 1
    }
    modeOctal=1
    if [[ readMode -eq 1 ]] || [[ writeMode -eq 1 ]]; then
        printf "We're doing stuff to this file or folder...\n"
        if [[ readMode -eq 1 ]]; then
            modeOctal=`expr $modeOctal + 4`
        elif [[ writeMode -eq 1 ]]; then
            modeOctal=`expr $modeOctal + 2`
        fi
        *code to do stuff to setfacl on target*
    fi
    if [[ removeMode -eq 1 ]]; then
        *code to do stuff to setfacl -x permissions on target*
    fi
while true; do
    case "$1" in
        -h)
            getHelp
            exit 0
        ;;
        -r)
            readMode=1
            ;;
        -w)
            writeMode=1
            ;;
        -R)
            readMode=0
            writeMode=0
            removeMode=1
            ;;
        -t)
            shift
            targetFile=$1
            targetIsSet=1
            ;;
        --)
            shift
            break
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [[ $targetIsSet == 1 ]]; then
    main
    exit 0
fi

exit 0
```

Since you can count on things going in the same order everytime, you can be sure that your execution will be consistent no matter what order you go in. In this example, you also allow for someone using the -t option which requires a second argument to use '-h' to get help there instead.

You can use similar logic to put scripting in the functions that handle your '-i' or '-o' to behave differently if the next item is the other option (ex: `-i -o output.file` or `-o -i input.file`)